# Customize Legend Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, legend

I have Shots Map Visualization like this :

[image: Shots Map Visualization]

The code that i used look like this :

```py
pitch = VerticalPitch(half=True, goal_type='box',linewidth=1,line_color='white',pad_bottom= 0.21)
fig, ax = pitch.draw(figsize=(9, 8))
# hteam goals:
hteam_sc_g = pitch.scatter(hteam_df_g["start_location_x"], hteam_df_g["start_location_y"], s = hteam_df_g["xG"]*300+100,marker="o",c= 'red', ax=ax, alpha=0.7, edgecolors='red',linewidth = 1, label = " Goals")

# hteam non goals shots:
hteam_sc_ng = pitch.scatter(hteam_df_ng["start_location_x"], hteam_df_ng["start_location_y"],s = hteam_df_ng["xG"]*300+100,marker="o", c= 'none', ax=ax, edgecolors='cyan',linewidth = 1, label = " Shots")

fig.text(s=hteam + " Shots Map", x= 0.06, y= 0.95, fontsize=20,fontweight="bold")
fig.text(s='Final Champions League 2010/2011', x = 0.06, y=0.9, fontsize=15)

# Legend
for xG in [50, 100,200, 400]:
    plt.scatter([], [], c='none',edgecolors='gray',linewidth = 1, alpha=1, s=xG, label= 'xG')
ax.legend(title = 'Outcome', labelspacing=1, loc="upper center",ncol=6,frameon=True,fancybox=True, shadow=True,bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.01))
```

I wanna try to customize my legend to have a display like this :

[image: Expected Legend]

First what Im trying is remove label in xG using
`plt.scatter([], [], c='none',edgecolors='gray',linewidth = 1, alpha=1, s=xG, label= False)`
but the result looks like the image that i send with the txt "False"

Answer (score 0):

To remove the text "False" in the legend, you can simply set the label to be a string of only a space, `label = " "` instead of `label = False`. That way your circles will appear in the legend without any text accompanying them.